# How can I send a C++ String to node.js?

Tags: c++, node.js

Im very new to making C++ addons for node.js

So my Question is: Is there a way for an addon-function to return a String? And if so, How?
Further Explaining:

Lets say i have a string called std::string testString in my C++ Source File. When given following JS code:

`const myAddon = require('path'); console.log(myAddon.myFunc());`

It should output the data testString holds.

Sorry if something isnt understandable, this is my first Question here.

Edit: `const char* myChar = "Hello World";`  would also be okay. Top Priority is to send any kind of Text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use std::string in a C++ Addon for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539693/how-do-i-use-stdstring-in-a-c-addon-for-node-js)

Comment: @Botje it kind of helped, but i want to understand how it works too. So a Simple Showcase of Logging the ancient "Hello World" to the console would be the best. Still thanks for the afford of replying :)

Edit: The If Statements and other functions used there confuse me what is actually needed, and what is only there bc of the Question-Authors Goal. Thats the Point im trying to make

Comment: Returning a string from a function in a C++ addon is [the hello world in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Did you try following that? What did not work?

Comment: @Botje Logging Text as `const char*` does work perfectly fine: `args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, myChar).ToLocalChecked());` where `myChar` is type `const char*`. Doing this _directly_ with std::string doesnt work ofcourse. But atleast i can now send text to my js file, Thanks!

Comment: See `std::string::c_str()` to get a `const char *` out of a `std::string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an adapted version of the hello world example [in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html):

```
#include <node.h>
#include <string>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

std::string testString; // value is set elsewhere.

void MyFunc(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(
      isolate, testString.c_str()).ToLocalChecked());
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
  // this would be a good spot to set testString
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "myFunc", MyFunc);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)

}
```